# How can i fix "Cannot find module './commands/${file}'"

Tags: javascript, discord

how can i fix this . i want to create a code which is advance commands

code :

```
 const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
  for(const file of commandFiles){
     const command = require('./commands/${file}');
       
       client.command.set(command.name, command);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks ` instead of single quotes.

So

```js
const command = require('./commands/${file}');`
```

Should be

```
const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
```